# Power BI Connection to Databricks Methods

Tags: powerbi, databricks

I have successfully used the following Databricks documentation to connect to Power BI Desktop.

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/bi/power-bi.html

The first documentation suggests downloading and installing a JDBC/ODBC driver. It also suggests constructing a JDBC connection string (URL) that looks like:

```
jdbc:spark://<server-hostname>:<port>/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=<http-path>;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=<personal-access-token>
```

The second method doesn't require installing a JDBC/ODBC driver and suggests constructing JDBC connection stringl URL that looks like:

```
https://<region>.azuredatabricks.net:443/sql/protocolv1/o/5441075421675247/0221-211616-xxxxxxx
```

As I mentioned, I have managed to get both methods to work, but can someone please let me know what is the best method to use? Also, are there and advantages / disadvantages using one method over another?

Cheers

Comment: I would go with second option no downloading of JDBC/ODBC driver.
I also found it bit faster with compared to drivers.

Comment: That is what I thought, and what I was hoping to hear. However, I think the first method is the most recent method ... unfortunately neither document provide a date when the document was released...

Comment: The second option is good, a number of clients use it with out an issue. Will you be using Power BI in direct query of import mode on the tables? For import you may it the 4Gb export limit on the driver

Comment: @Jonee, yes I intend to use Power BI in direct query mode (at least that is what most of the companies I have worked as contractor has requested). However, the 4Gb export limit is good information - didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: I thought the export limit was 10Gb..